# Need a formula to pull data in from another sheet in a workbook and dynamically sort alphabetically

Tags: excel-formula

I'm looking for a way to display and sort data from another sheet in a workbook, if the data meets certain conditions. For example:

Sheet 1 contains 2 columns, "Name" and "Department". I want to grab the value of the cell in the "Name" column, if the corresponding cell in "Department" equals a specific value, i.e "HR", and display it on another sheet. I then want to sort the data on the second sheet, so the values are in alphabetical order. Additionally, I want to ensure that if another name and department is added to sheet 1, that sheet 2 will sort automatically, assuming that the new name and department meets the criteria to be displayed in the second sheet.

So far, I have a couple of half-working solutions:

`=INDEX(Name,SMALL(IF(Department="HR",ROW(Name)),ROW(1:1))-1,1)` will correctly display all "Names" if their department is "HR", and *only those rows*. Unfortunately, these will be sorted as they are on the first sheet.

`=SORT(IF(Department ="HR",Name,""),,-1)` will similarly display as above, but is still not sorted as per the values of the cells in sheet 1.

FYI, I've defined the Name column on sheet 1 as "Name", and the Department column in sheet 1 as "Department".

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: `=SORT(FILTER(Name,Department ="HR",""))`

Comment: Oh, my gosh... I think that's worked @P.b! You're a star! Can you elaborate on what the formula is doing for my knowledge?

Comment: Filter makes a Filter on the Names range where in the same row the Department equals HR and discards of any other values. SORT then sorts the filtered result.

Comment: You may even want to use `=SORT(UNIQUE (FILTER(Name,Department ="HR","")))` to get rid of duplicates if any.